# why does concatenation didnt occur after performing == operation in java

Tags: java, string

```
class StringCompare1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s1 = "darahas";
        String s2 = "darahas";
        String s3 = "darahas1";
        System.out.println(s1==s3+"hi");
        System.out.println(s2==s3+"hi");
        System.out.println(s1==s2+"hi");
        System.out.println(false+"hi");
    }


}
```

Result on running:

```
false
false
false
falsehi
```

1. Why `"hi"` is not getting concatenating in first three print statements?
2. Why is `s1==s2` printing `false`? both `s1` and `s2` should point to the same string literal in scp, right?

Comment: Order of operations. `s1==s3+"hi"` is `(s1 == (s3 + "hi"))` and **not** `((s1 == s3) + "hi")`. Notice that [equality is below additive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: The fact that it's not printing "falsehi" should hint to the fact that it's parsing that expression as `s1 == (s2 + "hi")`.

Answer (score 0):

The + operator has higher precedence than the == operator so the + is evaluated first.

When concatenating a string and primitive value, the primitive value is converted to a wrapper type object and then to string before it can be concatenated.

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s1 = "darahas";
        String s2 = "darahas";
        String s3 = "darahas1";

        System.out.println(s1==(s3+"hi")); 
        System.out.println(s2==(s3+"hi"));
        System.out.println(s1==(s2+"hi"));
        System.out.println(Boolean.valueOf(false).toString()+"hi");    
        
    }
}
```